# In an ASP.NET webpage, how do I find out how a button is handled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I have to make some changes in a legacy ASP.NET application. Both the aspx file I am currently working on and the code behind file have over 5000 lines.

There is a button on the surface labelled "Edit", and it has an ID of "EditButton". I want to find the code executed when it is clicked. There is no "onclick" attribute specified in the button declaration, and in the codebehind, there is no EditButton_Click method. Searching for "Editbutton" or just "edit" in the codebehind file yields no results at all.

I know pre-MVC ASP only superficially. I don't know what possibilities are there to assign a handler to the button beyond the standard ones. I thought of adding a breakpoint to each method, but this will be tons of work, not only setting the breakpoints, but also going through the ones which are executed during the page is loaded, before the button is even clicked.

How do I find the code executed by the button?

Comment: Place a breakpoint in page_load. Anycase, your button should do form post, which should cause `page load--> attached event`, etc.

Comment: The whole page_load consists of `if (Context.Request.Params["Id"] == null) { Response.Redirect("~/Uebersicht.aspx", true); }`, returning us to the master page if no ID for the current detail page was supplied. Nothing more.

Comment: May be the master page will have page_load. or you can attach it from client side. check the html rendered of the page. Whether you can see some hidden field like `__EventTarget` ?

Comment: Can you post the code of the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An experienced .NET web developer helped me solve the puzzle.

The site has a FormView, and the button is within the FormView. It turns out that, if a button within the FormView has a standard name ("EditButton" being one of these standard names), it automagically fires a special event of the Formview, in this case ModeChanging. But the code behind did not overload OnModeChanging, so my breakpoints never got hit.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no OnClick attribute specified in the markup, and you didn't find anything in the code behind where it's setting the event handler such as `EditButton.OnClick+=EditButton_Click;` then the button does nothing except cause a postback. You might check to see if there's OnClientClick because the button could be used to execute JavaScript function.

Want to verify it? Use Visual Studio's debugging tools.

Comment: But the button *does* something - when I start the application and click the button, the whole page is made editable, as it should. I just can't find the code which does the switch between showing and editing mode.

Comment: @RumiP. Like I said, use Visual Studio's debugging tools.